# ag-grid row drag and drop with draggable error

Tags: ag-grid

I had included this code into my ag-grid:

```
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions> {
  processRowPostCreate: (params) => {
    console.log(params.eRow.draggable);
  },
};
```

But after I compile it, It give me this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'draggable' of undefined
>       at processRowPostCreate (vessel-table.component.ts:51)
>       at RowComp.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.executeProcessRowPostCreateFunc (rowComp.js:169)
>       at RowComp.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowComp.js.RowComp.init (rowComp.js:116)
>       at RowRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowRenderer.js.RowRenderer.createRowComp (rowRenderer.js:634)
>       at RowRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowRenderer.js.RowRenderer.createOrUpdateRowComp (rowRenderer.js:515)
>       at rowRenderer.js:446
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at RowRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowRenderer.js.RowRenderer.redraw (rowRenderer.js:445)
>       at RowRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowRenderer.js.RowRenderer.redrawAfterModelUpdate (rowRenderer.js:210)
>       at RowRenderer.webpackJsonp../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/rendering/rowRenderer.js.RowRenderer.onModelUpdated (rowRenderer.js:144)

Is there anyway to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to refer https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/802#issuecomment-334525123

Basically, .draggable is a function from jquery-ui.